# Match two columns and give an output such that if one column has some value the other has NA, it reflects the value in R

Tags: r

```
Column1   Column2  Output
Match     Match    Match
Match     NA       Match
NA        NA       NA
```

The above are two columns and the desired output in R. Output should be,if both column is Match it should give a "Match",if one column has Match and the other has NA, it should still print "Match". But if both of them are NA's it should print it as NA

Comment: @Henrik glad you noticed that I particularly asked how to use coalesce(Which I actually didn't). We had many more ways which were not listed on your claimed duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pmax`

```
df1$Output <- do.call(pmax, c(df1, na.rm = TRUE))
df1$Output
#[1] "Match" "Match" NA
```

---

Or with `coalesce` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Output = coalesce(Column1, Column2))
#   Column1 Column2 Output
#1   Match   Match  Match
#2   Match    <NA>  Match
#3    <NA>    <NA>   <NA>
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Column1 = c("Match", "Match", NA), Column2 = c("Match", 
NA, NA)), .Names = c("Column1", "Column2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: That's a perfect solution, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
> df=NULL
> df$Column1=c("Match","Match",NA)
> df$Column2=c("Match",NA,NA)
> df=data.frame(df)
> df
  Column1 Column2
1   Match   Match
2   Match    <NA>
3    <NA>    <NA>
> df$Column3=ifelse(is.na(df$Column1)&is.na(df$Column2),NA,"Match")
> df
  Column1 Column2 Column3
1   Match   Match   Match
2   Match    <NA>   Match
3    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
```